# How to copy-and-paste value (Excel VBA)?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to do a simple copy-and-paste value from one Excel file to another using Excel VBA. I have the following code but it seems to copy-and-paste over the format as well. How can I specify it so it does paste value only? Thanks.

```
Sub PasteValue()

Set x = Workbooks.Open("workbook name 1")

Workbooks("workbook name 1").Sheets("sheet name 1").Range("A1:M10").Copy Workbooks("workbook name 2").Sheets("sheet name 2").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use:

```
Workbooks("workbook name 1").Sheets("sheet name 1").Range("A1:M10").Value = _
Workbooks("workbook name 2").Sheets("sheet name 2").Range("A1:M10").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Just paste values using:

```
Workbooks("workbook name 1").Sheets("sheet name 1").Range("A1:M10").Copy   
Workbooks("workbook name 2").Sheets("sheet name 2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: After adding that, I am getting the following: "Compile error: Expected: end of statement"

Comment: If you are referring to the correct book & correct sheet name with this code on 2 separate lines, there is no reason for this not work **unless** there is more code to your sub that you are not showing

Answer (score 0):

Paste values only: try this

```
Sub Paste()

'Declare ranges
    Dim Source_Rg As Range 'Copy from source range
    Dim To_Rg As Range     'Past to target range

'Set source and target ranges
    'Source range
    Set Source_Rg = Workbooks("Source file name.xlsx") _
                   .Worksheets("Sheet name").Range("A1")

    'Target range (Active workbook)
    Set To_Rg = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet name") _
               .Range("A1")

'Paste values only
    To_Rg = Source_Rg

    Source_Rg = Nothing
    To_Rg = Nothing

End Sub
```